# Fetching (new) mails from pop3 and add to mysql database

Tags: mysql, perl, pop3

anyone knows a simple tool for linux that just connect pop3 server, fetching (new) mails, and adding it to mysql table?
I just have started to code it in perl but i think someone did it already.

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: Use fetchmail, with the mda option set to be a script that takes an email message on stdin and inserts it into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full example for newbies: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/code-an-application-to-read-pop3-mailboxes-with-perl/6060855

You could use Net::POP3 or Mail::POP3Client to read pop3 and DBI to connect to mysql database.

Some tutorial:

http://sql-info.de/mysql/examples/Perl-DBI-examples.html
http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perlmysqlquery.php